# Build a React Docker Image with env vars and GitlabCI

Tags: docker, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a react app that is using a `.env` file that is not part of git as it contains credentials.

When I build my react app with docker manually:

```
docker build --no-cache  -f docker/prod/Dockerfile .
```

And then pushing the image, it will work with no problem.

But when I do the same thing with gitlab, as there is no .env in git, it will not resolve env vars.

How should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the credentials in your `.env` individually via Masked Environment Variables in the Gitlab-UI for your project (Your project → Settings → CI/CD → Environment variables). Those masked variables will show in job logs.

You can find details here: [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variables)